# MapView marker slightly moves when zooming out

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I'm using Google Map for my application. Using the exact code in [this guide from Google itself](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview), I managed to put a marker on the map using ItemizedOverlay.

But when I zoom out, the marker slightly moves to the left. The Circle Radius Overlay stay in place though

Here's a screenshoot of my app:

[image: Zoomed in]---------[image: Zoomed out]

It does not happen in the real Google Map apps:

[image]----[image]

**I** tried using hard-coded Geo point but the marker still slightly moves. Anybody know the solution of this?

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

Here's my ItemizedOverlay class

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context context;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    }

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        context = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return g_overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return overlays.size();
    }

    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        //...
    }
}
```

and here's the code that calls the above class

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin);
MyItemizedOverlay mio = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(mGeoPoint, "Your location", "");
mio.addOverlay(oi);
mapOverlays.add(mio);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that the cause of this is `boundCenterBottom` inside ItemizedOverlay constructor

I changed it to `boundCenter` and it stays in place after zooming out

```
public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker) {
    super(boundCenter(marker));
}
```